# Not all LSNs map to dates

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I'm building an ETL that processes data from SQL server's change data capture feature. Part of the ETL is recording logs about the data that is processed including the data import window start and end. To do this I use the function `sys.fn_map_lsn_to_time()` to map the LSNs used to import the data to the corresponding datetime values.

The function `sys.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_()` takes two parameters that are the start and end of the data import window. These parameters are inclusive so the next run needs to increment the previous LSN to avoid re-importing rows that fall on the boundary.

The obvious answers is to use the function `sys.fn_cdc_increment_lsn()` to get the next LSN before bringing in the data. However, what I found is that this LSN does not always map to a datetime using `sys.fn_map_lsn_to_time()`. The LSN is valid for use in the `sys.fn_cdc_get_all_change_()` but I would like to be able to easily and accurately log the dates that are being used.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE @state_lsn_str CHAR(22) = '0x0000EEE100003E16008F'; -- try using `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(<capture_instance>)` instead since this value won't work for anyone else
DECLARE @state_lsn BINARY(10) = CONVERT(BINARY(10), @state_lsn_str, 1);
DECLARE @incr_lsn BINARY(10) = sys.fn_cdc_increment_lsn(@state_lsn);

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(22), @incr_lsn, 1) AS incremented_lsn,
       sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(@incr_lsn) AS incremeneted_lsn_date;
```

This code returns an LSN value of **0x0000EEE100003E160090** and **NULL** for incremented_lsn_date

---

Is there a way to force an LSN to be mapped to a time?
**OR**
Is there a way to get the next LSN that does map to a time without risking losing any data?

Comment: I've used CDC in a couple of engagements and I'm wondering why it's important to you to be able to map an LSN to a time. LSNs are the native way for CDC to track its position in the stream. Wallclock times make us humans comfortable, but trying to have CDC use them seems like an invitation for error. So in the cost/benefit calculus, there's some cost to it. What benefit are you getting for it?

Comment: Mapping the LSN to times allows me to accurately log the data import window. This is useful when troubleshooting issues with the integration. Saying that the last run imported data between two unreadable binary values isn't very useful. The ability to show the data import window also improves trust in the data processing. Sometimes there is benefit in making humans comfortable and making easy to understand logs.

Comment: As an aside I'm actually using `sys.fn_cdc_increment_lsn()` and just stating that the Window_start_datetime value is exclusive. Which avoids skipping over any LSNs and also allows me to create decent logs. However, I'm still curious as to whether my assumptions here are accurate. I'm not confident enough to use it in production code for a client but I thought it was interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the value returned from `sys.fn_cdc_increment_lsn()` doesn't map to a datetime is there was no change recorded for that specific LSN. It increments the LSN by the smallest possible value even if there was no change recorded for that date.

To work around the issue I used the `sys.fn_map_time_to_lsn()` function. This function takes a *relational operator* parameter. You can get the next datetime value by using 'smallest greater than' for this parameter. The following code returns the next LSN that maps to a datetime:

```sql
DECLARE @state_lsn_str CHAR(22) = '0x0000EEE100003E16008F'; -- try using `sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(<capture_instance>)` instead since this value won't work for anyone else
DECLARE @state_lsn BINARY(10) = CONVERT(BINARY(10), @state_lsn_str, 1);
DECLARE @state_lsn_date DATETIME = sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(@state_lsn);
DECLARE @next_lsn BINARY(10) = sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn('smallest greater than', @state_lsn_date);

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(22), @next_lsn, 1) AS next_lsn,
       sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(@next_lsn) AS next_lsn_date;
```

This code returns what appears to be a logical datetime value for the next LSN. Though I'm unsure how to 100% check that there is no data in any other tables.

The code above has a @state_lsn_date value of **2018-02-15 23:59:57.447** and the value found for the next LSN is **2018-02-16 00:00:01.363** and the integration runs at midnight.

---

The functions `sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time()` and `sys.fn_cdc_map_time_to_lsn()` use the `cdc.lsn_time_mapping` table to return their results. The documentation for this table states:

> Returns one row for each transaction having rows in a change table.
>   This table is used to map between log sequence number (LSN) commit
>   values and the time the transaction committed. Entries may also be
>   logged for which there are no change tables entries. This allows the
>   table to record the completion of LSN processing in periods of low or
>   no change activity.
>
> [Microsoft Docs - cdc.lsn_time_mapping (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/cdc-lsn-time-mapping-transact-sql)

As I understand it that means every LSN value in any change table will be mapped here. There may be additional LSNs but there won't be missing LSNs. This allows the code to map to the next valid change date.

Since all changes will have a mapping in the `cdc.lsn_time_mapping` table using this method shouldn't lose any data.

---

Do I sound a little unsure? Well, I am.

I'm hoping someone with a deeper knowledge of the SQL Server Change Data Capture system can confirm whether this is safe or not.